# Unexpected Error -

Tags: php, mysql

I'm very new to PHP, I was just looking at an example to set up a WAMP server and use PHP to connect with the server. I inserted some data into a table in the database and wanted to retrieve all the data using the PHP file.

When I try to check for the output by doing this:

" localhost/android_connect/get_all_products.php "

I'm getting this error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$response' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\wamp\www\android_connect\get_all_products.php on line 5

This is the example:

```
    <?php
    // array for JSON response

    $response = array();
    $db = new DB_CONNECT(); 
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM products") or die(mysql_error());

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $response["products"] = array();
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

            $product = array();
            $product["id"] = $row["id"];
            $product["name"] = $row["name"];
            $product["price"] = $row["price"];
            $product["description"] = $row["description"];
            $product["created_at"] = $row["created_at"];
            $product["updated_at"] = $row["updated_at"]; 
            array_push($response["products"], $product);

        }
        
        $response["success"] = 1;
        echo json_encode($response);
     } else {

        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No products found";
        echo json_encode($response);

    }
    ?>
```

I understand that its syntax error, but I cannot find where exactly.

Comment: The code that you have pasted does not have the error that you have mentioned.

Comment: If you're only just starting to learn, please, please, please start by learning MySQLi or PDO with prepared statements/bind variables rather than the old deprecated MySQL extension.... get into good practises when you first start learning, and then you won't  have to unlearn and relearn in the future

Comment: Thanks for the advise @Mark. I will do the same

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code please check below

```
<?php
// array for JSON response

$response = array();
$db = new DB_CONNECT(); 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM products") or die(mysql_error());

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

        $product = array();
        $product["id"] = $row["id"];
        $product["name"] = $row["name"];
        $product["price"] = $row["price"];
        $product["description"] = $row["description"];
        $product["created_at"] = $row["created_at"];
        $product["updated_at"] = $row["updated_at"]; 
        $products[] = $product;

    }

    $response["products"] = $products;
    $response["success"] = 1;
    echo json_encode($response);
 } else {

    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No products found";
    echo json_encode($response);

}
?>
```

Comment: There was no syntax error in the code, what have you modified which would fix a non existent error?

Comment: @Hanky Just i improvised his code. Have you found any bug in my code :)

Comment: Although I did not down vote but that's not the point, this is a question answer site and the answers we post here, imo, should be an attempt towards the solution to the questions posted. `Improving` someone's code is not the solution to their question if that was not it. P.S. Its `improved`, `improvised` would mean something else. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This may be the reason

1)

> $result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM products") or die(mysql_error());

in that line you are storing the output to result variable might be the error line...

USE the below format... it works like champ :)

```
 $Result = mysql_query($sql, $conn); 
if (!$Result){ 
echo "<br>** Error in database table <b>".mysql_error()."</b><br>$sql"; 
}
else
{
   //do something you want to do...
}
```

Hope this helps....